# Plot a matrix as a single point in space

Tags: python, matrix, plot, graph-theory

I have a dataset of drugs represented as a graph, each of which is described by three non-square matrices:

1. edge index (**A**), an 2xe matrix, where e are the bonds of the molecule, the first line indicates the node (atom) from which the edge (bond) starts, and the second one the node where the edge arrives;
2. node feature matrix (**X**), an nx9 matrix, where n are the atoms of the molecule and 9 are the features used to describe these (e.g. atomic number, charge, hybridization);
3. edge feature matrix (**E**), an 4xe matrix, where e are the bonds of the molecule and 4 are the features used to describe these (e.g. type of bond, geometry).

[image]

I would like to plot these data on a Cartesian space to see if clusters are created based on their activity label. I thought, if I can reduce each matrix to a single point in space for each graph I will have three x, y, z coordinates, and then it will be very easy to plot the points. Does this make sense in your opinion? How could I go about turning a matrix into a single point using python? Finally, I leave you with an example of the graph I would like to create
Thank you all!

[image]

Comment: I would use [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and plot in 3d using the first three components as coordinates.

Comment: Why is the adjacency matrix of the graph non-square?? It should be square!

Comment: @Stef sorry is not an adjacency matrix but an edge index matrix, scuse me for the mistake

Comment: @Stef Should I make a pca for each matrix and for each one plot the first three coordinates?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about your problem, and in particular your graphs and what they represent, to have any idea what kind of representation would be sensible.

Comment: @ravenspoint thanks for your comment, I added an example to my post. I have a dataset of 3k molecules represented like this

Comment: Thank you for the example.  Things are much clearer now.

Comment: @ravenspoint oh yes, I use NetworkX to work with graph and PyTorch geometric to create graph neural network

Comment: In your example the features all have values that are small integers.  Can I assume that will always be true?  Can I also assume that you will never need more than 9 different node features or more than 4 different edge features?

Comment: Your example is in the form of an image.  Could you provide the node and edge matrix examples in a convenient computer readable form - my preference would be space delimited text files.

Comment: I do not understand the edge feature matrix in your example.  By my count your molecule has 9 bonds.  Why does your edge feature matrix have 18 columns?

Comment: @ravenspoint I got 18 columns because I use an undirected graph, If you look at the matrix A in fact the columns can be read as pairs (0-1 1-0, 1-2 2-1…), it is to indicate that the bond can be read from both directions

Comment: @ravenspoint Your assumptions are all right, what kind of file would you like?

Comment: @ravenspoint I had an idea: if I multiply a matrix by its transpose I get a square matrix. Now I can calculate the determinant of the matrix and use that as the Cartesian coordinate. I thank you for the great contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- The nodes in a drug's graph represent features that every drug has to different extents, including zero.
- The structure of a drug's graph models the extent to which every feature applies to that that drug
- There is an algorithm to calculate from a drug's graph the 'extent' ( a number ) each feature applies the the drug

Then:

- Construct a table where each row models a drug and each column is for a feature.  Each cell then contains the "extent" to which the column's feature applies to the row's drug.
- Apply the K-Means algorithm to the table.

The challenge is, of course: an algorithm to calculate from a drug's graph the 'extent' ( a number ) each feature.

IMHO the first step is to enter your data into a graph theory library.  I see you are using Python.  Python folks generally use a library called networkx.  Are you familiar with this library?

Personally, I much prefer to work with C++ ( it gives the performance required for large problem sets )  Recently, I added a SMILES parser to my C++ graph library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Convert the SMILES representation of each drug to its graph representation
- Calculate the graph edit distance ( GED https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance ) between every pair of drugs
- LOOP GEDMAX from 1 to 10

  - Add a connection between two drugs if the GED is less than GEDMAX.  This forms a new graph we can call "GEDgraph"
  - Find the components ( clusters of drugs all reachable from each other in the GEDgraph )
- SELECT "best" set of components